# Reading an excel file from C

Tags: c, excel

I used C program to write into an excel file and it worked for both (.xls & .xlsx)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE * fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen ("cfile.xls","w");

    fprintf(fpointer, "Name \t MIT 801\t MIT 802\t MIT 803\t MIT 805\t MIT 821 \n Haphyz\t 90\t 89\t 99\t 95\t 96\n");

    fclose(fpointer);


}
```

I also tried to read from it and it also worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE * fpointer;

    fpointer = fopen ("cfile.txt","r");

    char Creader[200];
    while (!feof(fpointer)){
        fgets (Creader,200,fpointer);
        puts (Creader);

    }
        fclose(fpointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm trying to use C program to  read an excel file that was created from the computer (not from C) but all I get is gibberish...nothing meaningful for both `.xls and .xlsx` then I decided to use the `.csv` format which worked but was only able to read only the first line of the excel sheet. Please how do I go about this?

Comment: You never wrote an Excel file.

Comment: xls and xlsx files are different formats, and neither of them would support the string that you wrote.  For example, an xlsx file is really a pkzip format file.  You would need to use a library like `libxl` to do this.

Comment: *an excel file that was created from the computer (not from C)* where are you running your C code?

Comment: In so far as Excel is sometimes used to simply store tabular data, Excel files can be saved as csv files and Excel can open csv files. The easiest way to write data so that it can be opened as an Excel file is to just write it in a csv format.

Comment: How many lines was the csv file and what was the behavior - how was it unable to read past the first line?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, the `.csv` format works fine the problem was with my code. I closed the file inside the loop so the program stops reading after the first line .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    FILE * fpointer;    
    fpointer = fopen("Book1.csv","r");
    char spreadSheet[200];

    while(!feof(fpointer)){
    fgets(spreadSheet,200,fpointer);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", spreadSheet); 

    fclose(fpointer);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

There is no way this would return an error message ,so it printed out what I instructed it to .

Thanks for your contributions.I'll make sure to look at my code better next time